A person teleports from a jail cell at the end
I'm trying to remember an episode from a (science fiction) type of series that probably aired in the 90's. 
It was a science fiction series like Twilight Zone or Outer Limits 90's, I know there was a voice over at beginning and end like those shows also. 
From what I remember the main character (middle aged white male) was on the run because he was trying to hide a fantastic secret contained in a notebook.  I believe he could teleport, but not all the time for some reason. 
At the end of the show he is locked in a jail cell and desperately needs to escape to save his secret from coming out (and perhaps being used for evil purposes). 
So he teleports himself outside to escape and I remember him burning pages of a notebook, so his secret could not get out. The ending sparked a sense of wonder and imagination. 
I saw it more than once but cannot recall anything else. And this is in color so at the least it would be in the remade versions of the shows listed above.

Episode "Room 2426" of the Twilight Zone series (1985-1989)
IMDb:

Biochemist Martin Decker is imprisoned, interrogated, and tortured,
  but still refuses to reveal a secret formula to his captors. However,
  his new cell mate's knowledge of teleportation of living matter may
  provide him with an escape route.

From Wikipedia:

Martin, still using the method Joseph taught him, actually disappears
  in a brilliant flash of light. Ostroff and Joseph are mystified as to
  how he escaped. It was just a trick, Joseph tells Ostroff, he couldn't
  have actually done it. Martin is now in a field with the notebooks,
  burning them in a campfire...

You can watch the episode here:




OK, I wasn't aware of the fact that there was a third TZ series. I meant the second one (the first revival) that ran from 1985 to 1989. But the info is there if you click on the IMDb link.

"there are three that came out after the original." - To the best of my knowledge, there are 3 TZ series. The original first one (1959-64), the 2nd one (the first revival, 1985-89) and the 3rd, the latest one (2002-03). So either there is a 4th one (the 3rd after the original), or your phrasing is incorrect. Is there a 4th one?

You got it Casspir! I will be watching this episode again ASAP. It will be fun to see if it holds up to how I (partially) remembered it.

Great! Please also mark my answer as the correct answer, there is an option for that. Thanks.
